# Get name of last dataframe accessed and insert that name in subsequent code

Tags: r, dataframe, reference, substitution

I would like to save the name of the last dataframe used and then use that name in code moving forward. SAS provides this feature via `%syslast` and `_last_` system variables. Is there an R equivalent? Would like to do something like this:

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
lastDF$newVarnames <- paste(lastDF$oldVarnames, "baseline", sep = "_") #do something to the mydf1 dataframe
 
mydf2 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
lastDF$newVarnames <- paste(lastDF$oldVarnames, "baseline", sep = "_") #do something to mydf2 dataframe
```

Want to use a reference like `lastDF` instead of the actual dataframe name. Also, would like to avoid just doing

```
lastDF <- mydf1, mydf2, ...
```

Comment: There's no such variable in R. In  R you would write a function to take care of the transformations you need to perform on an object. The parameter you pass to that function will act like variables for you. If you want to transform multiple objects and combine the results, you probably want to use something like `purrr::map_dfr`. In R we try to avoid variables names with indexes in them. It's easier to work with such data in lists in R,

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this feature does not exist in R. The closest thing is `.Last.value`, which holds the result of the most recently ran command.

##### Base R

The base R approach to apply identical code to multiple objects, would be to apply a custom function. You'll still need to specify the object's name:

```
doSomething <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- paste(names(df), "baseline", sep = "_")
  return(df)
}

mydf1 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
mydf1 <- doSomething(mydf1)

mydf2 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
mydf2 <- doSomething(mydf2)
```

##### Magrittr `%>%` pipe

The forward pipe `%>%` from the `magrittr` package allows us to send the output of `data.frame()` directly to `doSomething()` (as the first argument), so we can make a nice one-liner:

```
library('magrittr')

doSomething <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- paste(names(df), "baseline", sep = "_")
  return(df)
}

mydf1 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data')) %>% doSomething()
mydf2 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data')) %>% doSomething()
```

##### In-place data modification

For comprehensiveness: Some people coming from other programming languages are used to in-place modification of variables (passing by reference). This is not commonplace in R, but it is possible with a little hack using `assign()` + `deparse()` + `substitute()`:

```
doSomething <- function(df) {
  df.temp <- df
  names(df.temp) <- paste(names(df.temp), "baseline", sep = "_")
  assign(deparse(substitute(df)), df.temp, envir = parent.frame())
}

mydf1 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
doSomething(mydf1) # note that this time we don't need to manually store the output of `doSomething()` back into `mydf1`

mydf2 <- data.frame(x = c('my data'), y = c('more data'))
doSomething(mydf2)
```